# Using multiple pipes in c

Tags: c, operating-system

I wan't to write a program that uses 2 pipes to pass values between parent and child process.Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int mkfifo(const char *path, mode_t mode);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd,df,val;
  char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
  mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

  char * myfifo2 = "/tmp/myfifo2";
  mkfifo(myfifo2, 0666);

  pid_t c=fork();

  if(c==0){
    df = open(myfifo2, O_RDONLY);
    read(df, &val, sizeof(val));
    close(df);
    val= val+10;
    df = open(myfifo2, O_WRONLY);
    write(df, &val, sizeof(val));
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY); //if i put this write first print works and program finishes
    write(fd, &val, sizeof(val));

      }
  if(c>0)
   {
    val=1;
    df = open(myfifo2, O_WRONLY); 
    write(df, &val, sizeof(val)); 
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, &val, sizeof(val));
    printf("val is %d \n",val);

        }
}
```

The first read of the child waits for parent to write val inside the fifo file.After that it writes a new val into this fifo file and afterwards writes a value into the second text file.The  read in parent's code waits for this write to happen.So,all in all what i want is the parent process to execute the print only after the child process has written val in myfifo2 file.That is the purpose of the second named pipe i have used.However,this code gets stuck and prints nothing.I noticed that if i change the turn of the two write in child process it works but it does not satisfy the above thing i need.Why is this happening and how do i solve this?

Comment: Why are you using named pipes for this?  Use `pipe` to create the pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What's happening

While named pipes *can* be used with buffering (as you intend them to), relying on it to not block your program (because that's what you have, a **deadlock**) is a really bad practice.

Moreover, it comes with some caveats:

- In order to have that "buffering" effect, the both ends of the pipe need to be opened ([`man 7 fifo`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo))

  > The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed. Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.
- Writes will eventually block once the pipe reaches it capacity.  This size depends on the system but can be set via `F_SETPIPE_SZ` [`fcntl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html).  But also:

  > Note that because of the way the pages of the pipe buffer are
  >             employed when data is written to the pipe, the number of bytes
  >             that can be written may be less than the nominal size, depend‐
  >             ing on the size of the writes.

So, you have this situation:

- Parent (probably, could be even not yet there) waits in `read` on `/tmp/myfifo`.
- `/tmp/myfifo2` is opened `WR_ONLY` by parent.
- child calls `df = open(myfifo2, O_WRONLY);`, opening `/tmp/myfifo2` *also* as `WR_ONLY`.  Thus the read end of the pipe is **not** opened, therefore the call to `open` blocks.
- **Deadlock**.

**To solve this, opening `myfifo2` in the child as read-write *should* be sufficient.**

```
df = open(myfifo2, O_RDWR); // instead of df = open(myfifo2, O_WRONLY);
```

IMO this communication pattern looks a bit strange (and hard to understand), though.

Comment: Thank you sir for your detailed answer.Indeed using 0_RDWR works.Just one minor question.Why isn't the read from the child reading the value written by father before the child executes the write line?